# How to combine Json Web Token(JWT) and google oauth using passportjs, passport-google-oauth and node to create social login system?

Tags: node.js, jwt, google-oauth, passport.js

I need a working example tutorial. I understand the concept of JWT well. I want to learn to implement JWT with Google oauth login.

I can't find any concise, clear, and complete tutorial. 
Please refer me books, tutorials, or examples.

Answer (score 1):

This [ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) explains everything you would like to implement using node and express

Answer (score 1):

**The basic work-flow**:

**first** when the user login you generate a token consisted of specific signature for example a string of hashed ( user_id + 'random_string' ) and save it into your database.

**then** send the generated token with header for example

```
'x-auth': generatedToken
```

**after** that whenever user makes a request you need to check for the **request's header** if it contains 'x-auth' header if so you check if this `'x-auth'` matches the one in your database.